# How to secure composer-rest-server after generating REST API?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have configured composer-rest-server. I had also provided fabric username/password while configuring composer-rest-server (WebAppAdmin or admin). Now, I can able to access REST API without providing any credentials (through postman or loopback).

I would like to understand how we can secure composer-rest-server. Though, I have understood that we can add participant and issue identity, but not able to connect logical dots in context of how everything will work.

- How to secure composer-rest-server while accessing REST API?
- When and How we are going to use "username/secret" registered against any participant?
- When to authenticate composer-rest-server API and When to use participant identity to access business network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the documentation on this subject:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html

Comment: Thank You Simon. I saw this document, but what i am bit confused about the part that how composer-rest-server is going to manage identity, private key , certificates and wallet.

I have clarity about we can use passport strategy of our choice to secure composer-rest-server, but then  how rest-server later is going to manage wallet? I've following queries

- Who and How to administrate composer-rest-server? Will have to write separate application to administrate composer-rest-server? 
- How can we configure composer-rest-server to store different identity and wallet at different location?

Comment: It would be great if you can share some diagram if you have.

Comment: Comment from Deepak, which points to my Stack Overflow post that explains the whole authentication flow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655553/how-to-authenticate-to-rest-api-and-map-to-fabric-credentials