# Hyperledger Composer and Authentication

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i'm currently working on a POC application using hyperledger composer. I'm creating a mobile app which uses the client-SDK for interacting with my hyperledger network. I'm wondering how authentication works. Enrolling a new user works fine, i can enroll a new user being an admin and i receive the enrollmentID and enrollmentSecret. The documentation tells me the enrollmentSecret is used as confirmation for the CA to generate a certificate and corresponding keys.

The SDK gives me the idea that i'm authenticating by using only the enrollmentID and enrollmentSecret instead of the certificate and keys.

Quoting another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655553/how-to-authenticate-to-rest-api-and-map-to-fabric-credentials) i found:

*When a participant enrols using the enrolment ID and secret, an enrolment certificate is generated and placed into their wallet (configured using the keyValStore property in the connection profile). Once the enrolment certificate has been generated, the enrolment secret is made invalid. The secret can be only used one time - it is not a password.*

However what i want to do is give the "identity" total ownership of the certificate and keys so they can use it to authenticate on the network (maybe turn it into physical form / paper wallet). Looking at the SDK documentation this doesn't seem possible and i currently have no idea how it works if the only way to connect to the network is supplying the enrollmentId and secret.

Or does the SDK automatically store and use the certificate in the stored in keyValStore(connection profile) to authenticate? If so is it possible to manage this programmatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Composer issues new identities by using the Hyperledger Fabric certificate authority (CA) to register new enrollment certificates. The Hyperledger Fabric certificate authority generates an enrollment secret that can be given to the participating identity, who can then use the enrollment secret to request their enrollment certificate and private keys from the Hyperledger Fabric certificate authority.

See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/managing/identity-issue.html

You then bind a participant (added to your business network) to that identity and that identity is used to submit transactions to the Fabric blockchain. So the authority to do so is via the metadata in the connection profile  (pointer to the KeyValStore for the user in question) and the id's certificate in that KeyValStore.

Check out the Hyperledger Composer docs.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/managing/identity-bind.html